# setting session variable available to all sessions of splitter

Tags: session, variables, mule, splitter

I have a situation where I am reading multiple files in one flow using collection aggregator. I then use a splitter to split the files to process one by one. Now, I want to put some elements of the file into a map and I want this map to be available to all sessions of splitter so that I can populate it for every file.

setting it withing the scope of file processing i.e after the splitter on makes it available to the current session of file processing. However, I was thinking of declaring the session variable as null before the splitter. Would that be available to all sessions after splitting?

I think it is as I saw for the first file process. I want to know also how to set the session variable as null. I didn't seem to find it. Also any other solution to the situation would be appreciated.

Here's my flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json"
    xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
    xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">
    <flow name="dictionary_keywordsFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="D:\mJunction\CATALOG INTEGRATION TO BE MODIFIED\sOURCE FILES\Read_dir" connector-ref="Filefinal" pollingFrequency="10000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" moveToDirectory="D:\mJunction\CATALOG INTEGRATION TO BE MODIFIED\sOURCE FILES\Read_dir\backup">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="BSL.*" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <!-- <set-session-variable value="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]" variableName="filename" doc:name="Session Variable" /> -->
        <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" value="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]" doc:name="Property"/>
        <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
       <!--  <custom-transformer class="AddContainerMapSessionvalue" doc:name="Java"/> -->
         <splitter expression="#[payload]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
            <logger message="&gt;&gt;&gt; flow to extract keywords and create dictionary" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <logger message="Payload received for maeterial list is #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Original Payload"/>
            <splitter expression="#[xpath3('//CATALOGUE',payload,'NODESET')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
            <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
            <json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON"/>
            <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
            <logger message="payload is #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <custom-transformer class="com.mjunction.transformers.DictionarykeywordsGenerator" doc:name="Java"/>
            <logger message="payload is #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <logger message="session variable is #[sessionVars.container_map]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
             <file:outbound-endpoint path="src/main/resources/dictionaryfiles/output" outputPattern="output.txt" connector-ref="Filefinal" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>




    </flow>
</mule>
```

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

You can define null session Variable as below

```
 <set-session-variable variableName="fileName" value="#['']" doc:name="Session Variable"/>.
```

Yes, if you define session Variable before splitter and storing map( hoping you are getting this map from initial payload)will available through the session.

After splitter if you use session, everytime if the payload structure where you are extracting and storing in session is same, off- course it do override, such case you can use cache kind of concept. Refer: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/cache-scope, `or` When you store it for the firstTime split and to  use the case for the next sessions do a small condition check `#[sessionVars['fileName'] != null? 'true':'']`. Based on that you can construct the pending logic.